# React Sentry _mergeOptions is not a function

Tags: reactjs, react-router, sentry

I've just followed the directions at [Sentry docs](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/javascript/guides/react) to set up Sentry with React and React Router and it's not working. I'm using React `v18+` and Sentry `v7+`. Any issue reported to Sentry is displayed like that:

**TypeError ?(bundle)**
o._mergeOptions is not a function

The stack trace points the error to `./node_modules/@sentry/core/esm/integrations/inboundfilters.js` suggesting that the problem is on Sentry.

This is the React entry point code I have:

```js
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import * as Sentry from '@sentry/react';
import { BrowserTracing } from '@sentry/tracing';
import {
  RouterProvider,
  createBrowserRouter,
  createRoutesFromChildren,
  matchRoutes,
  useLocation,
  useNavigationType,
} from 'react-router-dom';
import './assets/styles/global.css';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import Home from './pages/home';
import Error from './pages/error';
import MyAppointments from './pages/my-appointments';
import Meetings from './pages/meetings';
import CancelAppointment from './pages/cancel-appointment';
import { useEffect } from 'react';

// basic sentry setup without react-router
// if (process.env.REACT_APP_SENTRY_DSN) {
//   Sentry.init({
//     dsn: process.env.REACT_APP_SENTRY_DSN,
//     integrations: [new BrowserTracing()],
//     environment: process.env.NODE_ENV,
//     tracesSampleRate: 1.0),
//     release: process.env.REACT_APP_SENTRY_RELEASE,
//   });
// }

// sentry setup with react-router instrumentation
if (process.env.REACT_APP_SENTRY_DSN) {
  Sentry.init({
    dsn: process.env.REACT_APP_SENTRY_DSN,
    integrations: [
      new BrowserTracing({
        routingInstrumentation: Sentry.reactRouterV6Instrumentation(
          useEffect,
          useLocation,
          useNavigationType,
          createRoutesFromChildren,
          matchRoutes,
        ),
      }),
    ],
    tracesSampleRate: parseFloat(process.env.REACT_APP_SENTRY_TRACES_SAMPLE_RATE || '0.2'),
    environment: process.env.NODE_ENV,
    release: process.env.REACT_APP_SENTRY_RELEASE,
  });
}

const sentryCreateBrowserRouter = Sentry.wrapCreateBrowserRouter(createBrowserRouter);
const router = sentryCreateBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: '/',
    element: <Home />,
    errorElement: <Error />,
  },
  {
    path: '/my_appointments',
    element: <MyAppointments />,
    errorElement: <Error />,
  },
  {
    path: '/meetings',
    element: <Meetings />,
    errorElement: <Error />,
  },
  {
    path: '/cancel_appointment',
    element: <CancelAppointment />,
    errorElement: <Error />,
  },
]);

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement).render(
  <RouterProvider router={router} />,
);

reportWebVitals();
```

and these are my dependencies:

```json
  "dependencies": {
    "@sentry/react": "^7.34.0",
    "@sentry/tracing": "^7.35.0",
    "axios": "^1.2.3",
    "dayjs": "^1.11.7",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-countdown": "^2.3.5",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "6",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "simple-crypto-js": "^3.0.1",
    "typescript": "^4.9.4",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.0"
  },
```

I add an exception for testing purpose at `MyAppointments` like this `throw new Error('testing sentry error report');` but as explained Sentry always issues the same `TypeError ?(bundle) o._mergeOptions is not a function`. The problem persists even hardcoding the env vars or using basic set up without react router instrumentation.

Comment: I opened a bug at GitHub Sentry Repository https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-javascript/issues/7032

Comment: I'm facing the same error with Vue app. The reason, as I've checked on internet, was multiple Sentry instances, so the solution is to update all Sentry packages to the latest one: app, core, tracing, etc. Have you tried it, @matheus?